# Does cordova-plugin-file-transfer have a file size limit?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

When attempting to upload a file of size 3,461,681,689 bytes (3GB) using phonegap FileTransfer on android, the server fails to receive any data. A 1GB file succeeded. See code below for reference:

```
var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileName = fileEntry.name;
options.chunkedMode = true;
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI(domain + '/uploadbin'), resolve, rej, options);
```

Log output from adb is:

```
FileTransfer: Content Length: -833285408
FileTransfer: Sent 199 of -833285408
FileTransfer: response code: 200
```

Looking at FileTransfer.java seems to indicate that some truncation to 32 bit is occurring. Is there any specific file size limit imposed or is this perhaps a bug in FileTransfer.java? Or is there some option I need to pass in?

Comment: Hello Justin,
Have you find any solution on this point??
i am having problem on uploading high resolution image upload via file-transfer

Comment: I tried the latest version of the plugin and it seems to work without any issues.